# How to update deployed meteor app

Tags: meteor

How can i update a deployed app using meteor.

So i deploy my app  using

```
meteor deploy xxxxxxx
```

and to delete i do

```
meteor deploy --delete xxxxxx
```

how can i update?
It is not in the command line help also

when i type

```
meteor deploy --help
```

I get

```
Options:
--delete, -D  permanently delete this deployment
--debug       deploy in debug mode (don't minify, etc)
--settings    set optional data for Meteor.settings
--star        a star (tarball) to deploy instead of the current Meteor app
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Is your app hosted on meteor.com?

If so you only need to issue a

```
Meteor deploy XXXXX
```

Command again and it will update your app.

Meteor Deploy uses the same hotcode reload that the apps use.

Answer (score 0):

Just refresh the web page where you're making the changes and the meteor server will make itself restart! :)